# wrap #tags and @name in a string with href

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I am looking for a solution to replace #tags, @names and URL in a string and wrap these elements with a href.

my string value

```
{
content: What is role of semantic tech in enabling high-powered #bigdata, #bigdatamgmt, @name, http://bitly.com
}
```

my code so far

```
f_addcontent_links: function(data){

    var temp = data,
        hashtag_count = data.match(/#([^\s]+)/g),
        atTag_count = data.match(/@([^\s:]+)/g),
        newtemp, updated_content;

        console.log(hashtag_count);

    if(typeof(temp) !== "undefined" && temp.length > -1){

        for (var i = 0; i <= hashtag_count.length; i++) {
            newtemp = temp.replace(/#([^\s]+)/g, '<a href="//twitter.com/search?q='+hashtag_count+'">'+hashtag_count+'</a>');
                // .replace(/@([^\s:]+)/g, '<a href="//twitter.com/'+atTag_count[i]+'">'+atTag_count[i]+'</a>');
        }
        delete temp;
    }
    return newtemp;
},
```

my issue is that the string is getting replaced with the last #tag value in the string.
What is role of semantic tech in enabling high-powered **#bigdata,#bigdatamgmt** search? **#bigdata,#bigdatamgmt**

I need the string to be updated with the href wrappers around all #, @, url with the same value

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake, why are you using `delete` there?, you don't have a closure and delete is used to [remove properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) from objects not the objects themselves, that will probably just return false.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo yeah i removed it you can't `delete` variables.

Comment: delete temp is deleting the content attr. I am passing data.content[i] as a param to the function and if data.content[i] has #, @, or any href url, I want to wrap inside a href tag.

Answer (score 0):

### [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VdvkRPTLdL6ug7mcgtzP?p=preview)

***Note:** This isn't doing what i think you want...you'll need to edit your `for` loop please look at the contents of your `match` calls.*

**JS**

```
function f_addcontent_links(data){
    var temp = data,
        hashtag_count = data.match(/[^#]+([^,]+)/ig),
        atTag_count = data.match(/[^@]+([^,]+)/ig),
        newtemp, updated_content;

        console.log(hashtag_count);

    if(typeof(temp) !== "undefined" && temp.length > -1){
        for (var i = 0; i <= hashtag_count.length; i++) {
            newtemp = temp.replace(/[^#]+([^,]+)/ig, '<a href="//twitter.com/search?q='+hashtag_count+'">'+hashtag_count+'</a>');
        }
    }
    return newtemp;
}

window.onload=function(){
  console.log(f_addcontent_links("{content: What is role of semantic tech in enabling high-powered #bigdata, #bigdatamgmt, @name, http://bitly.com}"));
}
```

### Regex

**This will find the *#* elements**

```
[^#]+([^,]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/I0HiElL4pUXhn1tP)

---

**This will find the *@* elements**

```
[^@]+([^,]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ylhEh96-miW1N6rc)

Comment: I am not looking to extract the "name" from @name. I want to replace the existing "@name" with <a href src="twitter.com/@name">"@name"</a>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution using regex. It took my values from my array and updated all the string content within the content attr of my JSON object.

```
f_mod_content: function(data){          
            var update_content = data.replace(/(http(s)*\:\/\/[^\s]+\s*)/g, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>")
                                .replace(/#([^\s]+)/g, '<a href="//twitter.com/search?q=%23$1">#$1</a>')
                                .replace(/@([^\s:]+)/g, '<a href="//twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>');
                return update_content;
        },
```